# IFormFile - attribute for max file size in megabytes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

For IFormFile we have attribute:

```
[FileExtensions(Extensions ="jpg,png,gif,jpeg,bmp,svg")]
```

to check extension.

Is there any attribute to check file size in Megabytes or I have to write my own attribute? Because I would like to allow users for uploading files with max size = 2 Megabytes.

Comment: You need to write your own. Refer [this article](http://www.bradwestness.com/2014/09/24/client-side-file-upload-validation/) for an example (its for MVC using `HttpPostedFileBase`, but easier enough to modify for `IFormFile`

Answer (score 9):

You did not specify the Framework.

## ASP.NET:

You should specify the following in web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

## ASP.NET Core:

## IIS

write this code to your web.config ( this file is generated during publish)

```
       <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <!-- This will handle requests up to 10MB -->
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10485760" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
```

## Kestrel

1, MVC solution:

```
[RequestSizeLimit(10485760)]
```

in the ctrl => this is 10MB

2, Globally specify the IWebHostBuilder

```
  .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 10485760; //10MB
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, as of today we need to create a custom attribute. Here's a quick shot at it.

```
public class MaxFileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly long _maxFileSize;

    public MaxFileSizeAttribute(long maxFileSize)
    {
        _maxFileSize = maxFileSize;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        var file = value as IFormFile;

        if (file == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid file.");
        }

        if (file.Length > _maxFileSize)
        {
            return new ValidationResult($"File size cannot exceed {_maxFileSize} bytes.");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

and use it this way:

```
[MaxFileSize(10485760)] // For example, 10 MB in bytes
public IFormFile File { get; set; }
```